# Multiple fonts in code editor on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to use multiple fonts in code editor on IntelliJ?

I've recently fell in love with [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) font, and want to use it FlottFlott, as explained [here](https://medium.com/@docodemore/an-alternative-to-operator-mono-font-6e5d040e1c7e#.gq319be2k), which is something possible with editors like Atom and Sublime Text. But I couldn't find anything on IntelliJ.